# span current date time from 6 hours

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in database named **pagination table.**
and the columns are schedule time and actual time.

now from web page i am inserting actual time.and the actual time is today current time and display the Actualtime in same row.
but the problem is... after 12:00 am the page refresh the time automatically.but i want to display this actualtime upto 6 AM morning and after that the page refresh the content.

**this is my sql query to select actual time from database.
please suggest me how to add +6 hours in datetime.now function.**

```
$sql = "SELECT actualtime FROM pagination where Edition = '$Edition' AND city = '$city' AND DATE(created) = DATE(NOW())";
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: $sql = "SELECT actualtime FROM pagination where Edition = '$Edition' AND city = '$city' AND DATE(created) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 HOUR)"; BUT I WANT TO SELECT ACTUALTIME FROM NOW MEANS CURRENT INSERTED TIME UPTO 4AM AT NIGHT. FOR EXAMPLE --- IF I SUBMIT THE ACTUALTIME AT 10 PM ON 2014-09-09 THEN IT DISPLAY THE TIME UPTO 2014-09-10 UPTO 5AM AFTER THAT THE CONTENT WILL BE REFRESHED ACCORDING TO THE CONDITION. PLZ HELP ME........ –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT actualtime
FROM pagination
WHERE Edition = '$Edition'
  AND city = '$city'
  AND DATE(created) = DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR));
```

Comment: Manual for `DATE_ADD` for those interested: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: $sql = "SELECT actualtime FROM pagination where Edition = '$Edition' AND city = '$city' AND DATE(created) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 HOUR)";    BUT I WANT TO SELECT ACTUALTIME FROM NOW MEANS CURRENT INSERTED TIME UPTO 4AM AT NIGHT.  FOR EXAMPLE --- IF I SUBMIT THE ACTUALTIME AT 10 PM ON 2014-09-09 THEN IT DISPLAY THE TIME UPTO 2014-09-10 UPTO 5AM AFTER THAT THE CONTENT WILL BE REFRESHED ACCORDING TO THE CONDITION. PLZ HELP ME........